# R dplyr dynamic column selection

Tags: r, dynamic, count, dplyr

I'm trying to use count on two columns (var 1 and question) where one column (question) is dynamic. The code below was working when the variable names did not include spaces, but since they do include spaces there is an error.

```
df <- data.frame(`var 1` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 2` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 3` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 4` = c('a','b')

)

question <- 'var 3'

dfDynamic <- df %>% count_(vars = c('var 1', question))
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected numeric constant
1: var 1
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by using "quasiquotation", the official method to deal with dynamic column naming.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(`var 1` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 2` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 3` = c('a','b'),
                 `var 4` = c('a','b')

)

# Does not work:
question <- 'var 3'
dfDynamic <- df %>% count_(vars = c('var 1', question))


# Try this instead:

# "quote" the column name -In dplyr lingo, create a "quosure" 
question <- quo('var 3')

# Notice that you don't need to use "count_" anymore, 
# just invoke the quoted column name with "!!"
dfDynamic <- df %>% count('var 1', !!question)


dfDynamic
```

You'll get:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `"var 1"` `"var 3"`     n
      <chr>     <chr> <int>
1     var 1     var 3     2
```

Here's a tutorial with more examples, that also explains the logic behind quasiquotation: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html